# SDK manager Unknown host dl-ssl.google.com

Tags: android, ssl, sdk, eclipse-juno

I am unable to update packages in SDK manager , it shows Download interrupted: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com. I am not using any proxy and my Comodo firewall is also turned off.
I have also tried to run SDK with admin privileges. 
Anyone know how to solve this ? I have read many posts regarding this but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Have you tried pinging that domain name? It resolves for me here.

Comment: Yes , i have but it's still showing Unknown host error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is surely antivirus. Comodo firewall runs in background even if you disable the firewall and that causes problem with SDK . 
I too had the same problem.

1.run comodo settings

2.defense+

3.list active processes

4.add adb.exe to trusted processes

5.restart server: run "adb kill-server" "adb start-server"

For  Comodo 6.x

1.Open Comodo

2.Click Tasks Icon at right top

3.Click Advanced Tasks

4.Click Open Advanced Settings

5.Select Security Settings --> File Rating --> Trusted files from left panel

6.Click on the upward arrow icon at the bottom

7.Click Add --> add the adb.exe

Answer (score 4):

Its because you are not able to connect to to the official Android repo using HTTPS protocol. Simply change it to HTTP under Windows -> Android SDK Manager.

reference : [link](http://code2care.org/pages/download-interrupted-unknown-host-dl-ssl-google-com-android-sdk-manager/#)

Answer (score 2):

Set the HTTP proxy settings in Android SDK Manager by navigating to: Tools -> Options. This resolved the issue for me.